# Why does the error messagesaying debug target is missing keep coming up? I have done all the steps but the file doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-assembly

##### I am getting the following error message that keeps coming up,

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target
> `'C:\Users\alish\OneDrive\Documents\Trial\NEA\NEA\bin\Debug\NEA.exe'`
> is missing.
> Please build the project and retry, or set the
> OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at
> the correct location for the target assembly. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTAxe.png)

It was working fine but then I opened the file to test it and it showed up with this message.

---

<kbd>Here is what I tried so far,</kbd>

- I have deleted the Visual Studio and re-downloaded it.
- Deleted bin and obj files but it still doesn't work.
- I have done all of the suggested help on chats but it doesn't work.
- Each time I tried to remake the code it changed the name of.exe to what I named the file.
- I have tried creating a new file twice and remaking the code but this error keeps coming up

<kbd>Note:</kbd> It contains a database that is working fine and is correctly referenced.

Comment: Do not start debugging, do a build. Make sure you have no errors. Verify where the output is created.

Comment: @Jester I have tried all of this and stil doesn't work. Thank you, is there anything else I could try

Comment: So you had no errors? And the file mentioned in the error got created?